# Flutter Image Variable

Tags: flutter

I'd like to build the UI for a shop app and I don't want to make a file for every product, so I made a file called products, the problem I am having is that I don't quite know how I can pass the image data.

```
class Products {
  String id;
  String title;
  double price;
  AssetImage image;

  Products({
    @required this.id,
    @required this.title,
    @required this.price,
    @required this.image,
  });
}
```

This is the list where I use the model above.

```
final List<Products> _products = [

Products(
  id: '1',
  title: 'new shoes',
  price: 69.99,
  image: Image.asset('assets/images/BeatsPro'), //does not work...don't know how
),];
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Products {
  String id;
  String title;
  double price;
  String image;

  Products({
    @required this.id,
    @required this.title,
    @required this.price,
    @required this.image,
  });
}

final List<Products> _products = [

Products(
  id: '1',
  title: 'new shoes',
  price: 69.99,
  image: 'assets/images/BeatsPro.png',
),
];
```

to show Multiple image

```
_products.map((product){

 Image(image: AssetImage(product.image));

  }).toList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Because

```
var a = Image.asset(''); // type Image
```

but in Products you expect AssetImage as input

```
class Products {
  AssetImage image;
}
```

and A value of type 'Image' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'AssetImage'

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way**

```
class Activity {
  String imageUrl;
  String name;
  String type;
  List<String> startTimes;
  int rating;
  int price;

  Activity({
    this.imageUrl,
    this.name,
    this.type,
    this.startTimes,
    this.rating,
    this.price,
  });
}
```

And Create Another Class

```
class Destination {
  String imageUrl;
  String city;
  String country;
  String description;
  List<Activity> activities;

  Destination({
    this.imageUrl,
    this.city,
    this.country,
    this.description,
    this.activities,
  });
}

List<Activity> activities = [
  Activity(
    imageUrl: 'assets/images/stmarksbasilica.jpg',
    name: 'St. Mark\'s Basilica',
    type: 'Sightseeing Tour',
    startTimes: ['9:00 am', '11:00 am'],
    rating: 5,
    price: 30,
  ),
```

**And In your activity**

```
final Destination destination;
```

define above `build` function

```
              Image(
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      image: AssetImage(
                        widget.destination.imageUrl,
                      ),
                    ),
```